# WordPress Options Page Checkbox - How to Translate to Conditional Comment?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, conditional-statements

I'm working on a WordPress theme and I've created an options page that is already setup and functioning for inputs and textareas. Which can easily be carried to the template pages with:

```
<?php $options = get_option('kittytheme_options'); echo $options['kittens']; ?>
```

Now, how would one modify that to work as a checkbox conditional? The following is probably wrong in many ways, but should illustrate what I'm trying:

```
<?php $options = get_option('kittytheme_options'); if ( $options['kittycheckbox'] == '0' ) : ?>Theme By: <a href="http://someurl.com/">Company Name</a><?php endif; ?>
```

So basically the idea is that the link should show by default being equal to 0 or nothing. But, when the checkbox to hide this area is checked in the options it would equal 1 therefore hiding it.

From the options page/form here's the checkbox:

```
<input id="kittytheme_options[kittycheckbox]" name="kittytheme_options[kittycheckbox]" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( '1', $options['kittycheckbox'] ); ?> />
<label class="description" for="kittytheme_options[kittycheckbox]"><?php _e( 'Hide Kitty Credit', 'kittytheme' ); ?></label>
```

And the final validation function is:

```
function theme_options_validate( $input ) {
global $select_options;
if ( ! isset( $input['kittycheckbox'] ) )
$input['kittycheckbox'] = null;
$input['kittycheckbox'] = ( $input['kittycheckbox'] == 1 ? 1 : 0 );
return $input;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what your `$options` has in it, may be you can try print_r($options); to see what it outputs.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking here; if you want to know how to use php for saving checkbox value, or if you need to know how to evaluate the option. also note that "Conditional Comment" have nothing to do with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Your code is almost good exept for the `theme_options_validate` function that still work but it coded in a wrong fashion; below how it should be:

```
function theme_options_validate( $input ) {
   $input['hidecred'] = isset($input['hidecred']) ? 1: 0;
   return $input;
}
```

So i guess that the real problem is that you are not including the conditional statement in all the desired WP pages. most probably you are including it only in `page.php` and not in `page-blog.php` and so on...

```
$options = get_option('startuppro_options');
if ( $options['hidecred'] ){
  // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check first for whether or not the option has been set when dealing with checkboxes. Use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check for this.

```
if(isset($options['kittycheckbox'])){
    echo 'Theme By: <a href="http://someurl.com/">Company Name</a>';
}
```

Comment: Are your checkbox values even getting saved into your options table in your database?

Comment: I checked the box and placed Test1-5 for my other options saved and then copied out what's shown in the db:

`a:6:{s:8:"kittycheckbox";i:1;s:7:"bgcolor";s:5:"Test1";s:9:"textcolor";s:5:"Test2";s:8:"hscripts";s:5:"Test3";s:8:"fscripts";s:5:"Test4";s:9:"customcss";s:5:"Test5";}`

Looks like it's set to 1 which is what it's suppose to be if checked. So all seems good.

Comment: And if its not checked, are you getting a value of 0 or is it null?

Comment: It simply doesn't save anything to the db for the checkbox if unchecked. It's pretty much what I described in the beginning, the conditional should be if kittycheckbox = 1 do this otherwise do nothing which that part doesn't even need to be written as obviously by default it wouldn't do anything. It _seems_ pretty simple, but I can't presume to know that there isn't more to it.